# How to move full python virtual environment from one machine to another?

Tags: python, linux, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I have a python flask server that runs on a development machine (Linux) in a python virtual environment. Is there a straightforward way to completely move this virtual environment and all the installed packages to another machine for deployment? (Also Linux)

I do not want to have to use pip install on the deployment machine as it is embedded and seems to be having some issues with pip. I am wondering if there is way to move the entire virtual environment cleanly and get it to work on another machine.

Things I have tried:

- I have tried starting a new virtual environment on the target machine and doing

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

For whatever reason this isn't working. It installs a bunch of packages then just hangs and I have to restart the machine.

- I also tried copying the entire virtual environment then editing the activate file as recommended by the second answer in this post.
  ["venv activate" doesn't not change my Python path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390129/venv-activate-doesnt-not-change-my-python-path)
  It didn't seem to work cause when I ran the server I got a bunch of import errors (it was still searching the wrong path).

Comment: Does running pip with the `-v` or `--verbose` flag lend any clues as to why this "hangs"?

Answer (score 0):

Do `pip freeze` on your dev machine. This will give you list of all packages which you have currently installed on your machine.
Download wheel files for all of these packages from pypi.org one by one or you can use these [scripts](https://github.com/iamtalhaasghar/pypi-wheels-downloader).

Copy wheel files to your target machine in a folder say `wheels`. Write a bash script to list through all files in this folder and run `pip install package_name.wheel` command on every item to install those packages. You can use find for this: `find /path/to/wheels/folder -name "*.whl" -exec pip install {} \;`